# Outlook Permissions - full access

Tags: outlook, permissions, calendar, office365

I want to allow someone in my organisation to be able to add, view, edit all my events in my outlook calendar. I have given them delegate access to my calendar.

However, they are unable to add events with this level of permission.

Is there a higher access level to grant than delegate on outlook.

Comment: What code do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of Outlook calendar permissions

[Calendar permissions](https://www.alitajran.com/calendar-permissions-office-365-powershell/#:%7E:text=Calendar%20roles%20and%20permissions%20%20%20%20Roles,CreateSubfolders%2C%20DeleteOwn%20...%20%207%20more%20rows%20)

How are you adding these permissions? Some calendar permissions need to be made in Powershell. I would be glad to help if you would like assistance with that.

Comment: I found if I grant "can edit" permission it works on the web version of outlook. The desktop app does not.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions sync issue, easiest thing to do would be to have them rebuild their Outlook profile. 

Open Control Panel >
Go to mail >
Click Show Profiles >
Add a new profile >
At the bottom of the mail section select "always use this profile" >
Change that to the new one >
Click apply >
Then open Outlook >
Give it a few minutes then check for the calendar 
They may need to manually add the calendar but the permissions should be correctly assigned.